# Create exception for PHP so page does not crash

Tags: php, web-services, error-handling, exception, crash

I am trying to fix a problem for my website. It uses a third party that holds several of the subscription services.

The `index` page displays some of this services but it is just simply a small part of the page, but when the server that connects to the third party crashes my whole website crashes. I use a web service to obtain the data from the database and have a PHP to use the web service.

I thought I had the correct exception to catch any errors so if the Web Service is down it does not crash my website. Could anyone look at the code below and see any changes I could make to prevent the crash.

```
public function getIncomingReservations($outcome="")
{
    $html_code = '';
    $amount = 0;
    $reservationDetails = '';
    $reservationTitle = '';
    $reservationURL = '';
    $reservationDate = '';
    $noreservationsToShow = true;
    try
    {
        $reservations = $this->webService->getAllreservations();
        if(isset($reservations->Hotel))
        {
            if(!is_array($reservations->Hotel))
            {
                $reservations->Hotel = array($reservations->Hotel);
            }
            $html_code = '<dl>';
            foreach($reservations->Hotel as $reservation)
            {
                if($amount >= WebServicesWidgets::$MAX_incoming_reservations)
                {
                    break;
                }
                $reservationDetails = $this->webService->getreservationDetails($reservation->HotelId);
                if($reservationDetails->haseBusiness === true && $reservationDetails->isValidated === true)
                {
                    $noreservationsToShow = false;
                    $reservationTitle = $reservationDetails->shortName;
                    $reservationURL = $this->EWEBSITE_URL . $reservationDetails->HotelId;
                    $reservationDate = $reservationDetails->startDate;
                    $html_code .= '<!-- ' . $reservationDetails->HotelCode . ' | ' . $reservation->HotelId . ' -->';
                    $html_code .= '<dt><a href="'. $reservationURL . '">' . $reservationTitle . '</a></dt>';
                    $html_code .= '<dd>' . date('F j - g:i A', $reservationDate) . '</dd>';
                    ++$amount;
                }
            }
            $html_code .= '</dl>';
        }
        else
        {
            $html_code = WebServicesWidgets::$NO_reservationS;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        $html_code = WebServicesWidgets::$FAIL_MSG;
    }
    if($noreservationsToShow)
    {
        $html_code = WebServicesWidgets::$NO_reservationS;
    }
            if(empty($return)){
                echo($html_code);
            }
            else {
                return $html_code;
            }
}
```

Comment: What language is the code you posted (it doesn't look like javascript)? If this is the code producing javascript, could you post a minimal example of what is not working?

Comment: What do you mean by "crash" exactly? Does the webpage show any error? Are you seeing errors in the logs? Does the webpage get green and really angry?

Comment: @ArtjomB. the error we get is just a simple `500 Internal Server Error`. So for example two days ago the server ran out of space and it stopped running, and while the website was running fine, because the the server was unreachable the whole site went down. So far I haven't anger it enough to turn green.